# use of <$nopage> in python try-except block

Tags: python

I am seeing use of `<$nopage>` in some python scripts online and in a pdf file. I have googled for what it stands for. But could not get information about it. To be specific, in the PDF version of the book, Core Python Programming, I see this `<$nopage>` construct many times. But on the online version (Safari Books) of the same book, I do not see this construct. Can someone please tell me what this `<$nopage>` means? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means nothing in the context of Python at all. It's probably a mistake in the PDF rendering. I'm guessing it's a statement to prevent page breaks in the code.

Update: I finally found an example here:
http://raninho.com.br/~paper/Python/O%27Reilly%20-%20Core%20Python/237.html

That is indeed not python code, but most likely code to prevent page breaks. Pretend it's not there.